# AMQP connection lost doesn't kill parent process, so reconnection never happens

Tags: connection, elixir, amqp, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have init function of my GenServer. Supervisor is looking after it, and should restart it on exit.

```
  def init(_opts) do
    username = get_conf(:username)
    password = get_conf(:password)
    host = get_conf(:host)
    port = get_conf(:port)
    vhost = String.replace(get_conf(:vhost), "/", "%2f")
    {:ok, conn} = Connection.open("amqp://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}/#{vhost}")
    {:ok, chan} = Channel.open(conn)
    state = %State{
      exchange: get_conf(:exchange),
      channel: chan,
      routing_key: get_conf(:routing_key)
    }
    {:ok, state}
  end
```

When I restart RabbitMQ with `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart` new connection isn't established.

In debug bar I see following:
[image]
When I click on connection pid <0.417.0> I get message that process doesn't exist any more. It seems that process is dead and parent `AmqpTransport` know nothing about that.
How can I make `AmqpTransport` die together with it's child `Connection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with adding `trapping exits` and linking to `Connection` process. Also I pattern match errors during connection to avoid `reached_max_restart_intensity`.

```
  @restart_delay 2000 # 2 seconds

  def init(_opts) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    send(self(), :connect)
    {:ok, nil}
  end

  def handle_info(:connect, state) do
    #...
    case Connection.open("amqp://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}/#{vhost}") do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        Process.link(conn.pid)
        # ...
        {:noreply, state}
      {:error, :econnrefused} ->
        Logger.error("amqp transport failed with connection refused")
        Process.send_after(self(), :connect, @restart_delay)
        {:noreply, nil}
    end

  end

  def handle_info({:EXIT, pid, reason}, state) do
    Logger.error("amqp transport failed with #{inspect(reason)}")
    Process.unlink(pid)
    Process.send_after(self(), :connect, @restart_delay)
    {:noreply, nil}
  end
```

Comment: `Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)` is redundant there, this should be done somewhere in `init/1` callback of this process, there is no need to call it every time you reestablish the connection. Also, for clarity, you probably want to call [`Process.unlink/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html?#unlink/1) in `handle_info({:EXIT, _pid, reason}, state)` to unlink the died process.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, thank you! Reflected your suggestions in my answer.